# How to create multiple versions of one project in Visual C++ Express 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, version-control

I wish to create several small programs for the sake of testing and experimentation using an external library (SDL in this case). It is a bit of a tedious process to set everything up, so I would prefer not to have to do it repeatedly.

I would like to know if there is an easy way to either:

1. create a template that I can apply every time I wish to start a new project, such that the relevant include directories, etc. have already been added, or
2. copy/create a revision of an existing project so that it changes its name/target directories, etc. automatically, allowing me to work with several versions simultaneously.

Comment: You do this with project property sheets.  View + (Other Windows) + Property Manager to get started.  Not sure if Express supports them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio solutions - how to ensure project properties are shared?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414224/visual-studio-solutions-how-to-ensure-project-properties-are-shared)

Comment: @hans "Property Manager" does not appear to be in Express.

Comment: Well, you found a good reason to purchase a license for the retail edition.  That always happens, eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can set templates in vs-express buyt copying projects in a solution is easy.

1. Invent a solution name like **foobar** (do not use words likely to
   appear in a project file!)
2. Create a project based on **foobar** and add to a solution.
3. Copy **foobar** subdir to **foobar2** (this obviously can be any name you want)
4. In  **foobar2** edit 'foobar.vcxproj' and replace all 'foobar' with 'foobar2' - this assumes that foobar.cpp is foobar2.cpp in the 2nd  project - if it isn't, simpyl don't replace the .cpp entries.
5. Add foobar2 to the solution inside the IDE

Comment: What about the "ProjectGuid" field in the .vcxproj file? leave it/ change/ delete?

Comment: projectguid is generated/updated automatically when you add it to the solution